# How to set the name of DLL from which binary depends?

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl

In my program I'm using libcurl that is built with SSL support. So I have `libcurl.dll` that depends on `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. I need to change the names of `libeay32.dll` to `libeay32_10_x32.dll`. How to tell libcurl to use `libeay32_10_x32.dll` not `libeay32.dll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2696569/416627) talks about doing something like this. You have to edit the PE file and change the imported dll name. The one thing that question doesn't address is when the new name is longer or shorter than the original import name. If the length is different you run the risk of killing offsets in your executable that were calculated by the linker.

Given that libcurl is open source your best bet would be to rebuild it linking against your renamed libraries.

Comment: Thank you!
I've successfully rebuilt openssl to produce libs pointing to DLLs with specific names and then used them to build libcurl.